# Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I get the exception:

```
Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.
```

when I start my android project.

My build.gradle (Project: android)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.derdoenerdon.ressourcencockpit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'


    compile 'com.github.OPCFoundation:UA-Java:1.03.342.0'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.7'

}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

About any help, I would be very thankful. I am new in android. 
It happens, since I try to use firebase in my application and it added some dependency in my application automatically.
Thanks a lot

EDIT: 
This is how my gradle.build (Module: app) looks now:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.derdoenerdon.ressourcencockpit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'


    implementation 'com.github.OPCFoundation:UA-Java:1.03.342.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.7'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is the warning, which I get as output:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

Does anybody know, how to remove this warning? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add classpath

```
 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

in the project gradle in the dependencies not in the module.app gradle as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @NewGenerationFashion check after editing the answer and tell me if everything is okay :)

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } 

this is how the dependency look in the project gradle and I get this: 

Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files
 
-
Salam

Comment: buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
} 

Sorry, I delete this above in gradle.build of the Module:app 

and now I get this: 


The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' not 3.1.1

Comment: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Update Build Tools version and sync project
Open File 


I get this above..I would be happy, if you can help me out 
Thanks

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } 

I put this above and get still this warning: 
The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your

Comment: what happens when you remove buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

Comment: nothing.. I updated now the gradle.build, 

I edit my post, would be thankfull if you can help out. I just get warnings, but everything seems ok. If I can remove the warnings, would be more great

Comment: @NewGenerationFashion please try to replace each word in the (module:app) gradle as it shows in the warnings (example : androidTestCompile replace it with androidTestImplementation) etc. , try this and tell me the result please :)

Comment: thanks, I did it. I was confused, why I can remove something as "implementation" or as "api", because I would assume, that the semantic shall be different. 

But now, I only get one warning, but I dont know, how to remove it. 

I again edit it. Would be happy if you can take a look ;) 

Thank you :)

Comment: you will replace (compile) with (implementation) as compile keyword will be deprecated after 2018 , try this and tell me what happens :)

Comment: I dont have "compile" in the build.gradle (Module: app) anymore.. 
this is the only word "compileSdkVersion 25" with "compile" and if I replace this compile into implementationSdkVersion 25, I will get error

Comment: no don't change compileSdkVersion , if you are sure that there is no compile word , try to clean project then build project .. then tell me what you see again please

Comment: I did it. 
Now I get this only: 

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.


and I dont have compile in this gradle, but project was build successfully

Comment: @NewGenerationFashion please try to update classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' to 3.2.0

Comment: thanks, now everythings seems to work fine! 
I would be happy, if you could help me with firebase, its another question of me. 

Thank you and salam

Comment: good to hear that :) , I didn't use firebase a year ago , so I don't know if I will remember or not ,but I will see your question .. any way , good luck with your project ^_^

Comment: Thanks, you too, you help me a lot